# CSS - how to get first element of consecutive class

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, less

I have ten li having same class and between this having 4 consecutive class. how I can get the first element of consecutive class? with CSS

```css
.abc {
  color: red;
}

.abc + .xyz:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `nth-of-type(4)`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

```css
li {
  color: red;
}

li:not(.xyz) + .xyz {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can fix this another way:

```css
.abc {
    color: red;
}

ul .xyz {
    color: yellow;
}
        
ul > .xyz ~ .xyz {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc xyz">abc xyz</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
  <li class="abc">abc</li>
</ul>
```

Now only the first element with class xyz will be yellow, the other ones will be red.

Comment: `!important` is unnecessary, the specificity of your selectors is enough.